# Is there any way go get over .map is not a function type error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building an food ordering app using react
.I have build the backend for api calls,it seem to work fine.I am getting stuck in this.state.filteredRestaurantList.map is not a function error.Is there any solution to it?
Should i Change export defaults or is there any other way.
Is it due to getGridListCols!

```
class Home extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        restaurantList: [],
        filteredRestaurantList: [],
        }
    }

  getGridListCols = () => {
      if (isWidthUp('xl', this.props.width)) {
        return 6;
      }

      if (isWidthUp('lg', this.props.width)) {
        return 5;
      }

      if (isWidthUp('md', this.props.width)) {
        return 4;
      }
      if (isWidthUp('sm', this.props.width)) {
        return 2
      }
      return 1;
  }

  searchHandler = (value) => {
    if (value !== '') {
      this.findRestaurantApiCall(value);
    }else {
      this.getAllRestaurantsApiCall();
    }
  }

  itemClickHandler= (id)=>{
    console.log('id',id);
    this.props.setRestaurantId(id);
    this.props.history.push('/details');
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div style={{marginTop:100}}>
        <Header screen="Home" searchHandler={this.searchHandler}/>
        <div>
          <GridList cellHeight={'auto'} cols={this.getGridListCols()}>
            {this.state.filteredRestaurantList.map(item =>(
              <GridListTile key={item.id}>
                <HomeItem onItemClick={this.itemClickHandler} item={item} />
              </GridListTile>
            ))}
          </GridList>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getAllRestaurantsApiCall();
  }

  getAllRestaurantsApiCall = () => {
    let that = this;
    let url = `http://localhost:8080/api/restaurant`;
    return fetch(url,{
      method:'GET',
    }).then((response) =>{
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      }
    }).then((responseJson)=>{
      that.setState({
        restaurantList:responseJson,
        filteredRestaurantList:responseJson
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('error login data',error);
    });
  }

  findRestaurantApiCall = (value) => {
    let that = this;
    let url = `http://localhost:8080/api/restaurant/name/${value}`;
    return fetch(url,{
      method:'GET',
    }).then((response) =>{
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      }
    }).then((responseJson)=>{
      console.log('json',responseJson);
      that.setState({
        restaurantList:responseJson,
        filteredRestaurantList:responseJson
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('error login data',error);
    });
  }

}

function HomeItem(props){
  const{item} = props;
  return(
    <div className="home-item-main-container">
      <Card style={{width:280}}>
        <CardActionArea onClick={(e)=>props.onItemClick(item.id)}>
          <CardMedia
            component="img"
            alt={item.restaurantName}
            style={{objectFit: 'cover'}}
            height="140"
            image={item.photoUrl}
            title={item.restaurantName}/>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
              {item.restaurantName}
            </Typography>
            <Typography component="p">
              {item.categories}
            </Typography>
            <div style={{marginTop:25,display:'flex',justifyContent:'space-between',alignItems:'center'}}>
              <div style={{display:'flex',flexDirection:'row',backgroundColor:"#FDD835",padding:5,justifyContent:'space-evenly',alignItems:'center',width:80}}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon="star" color="white"/>
                <span className="white">{item.userRating}({item.numberUsersRated})</span>
              </div>
              <div>
                <FontAwesomeIcon size="sm" icon="rupee-sign" color="black"/>
                <span>{item.avgPrice} for two</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
      </Card>
    </div>
  )
}

export default withWidth(Home);
```

I expect that my home page is rendered without any error

Comment: have you done any debugging yet?

Comment: What error are you getting? From here it looks like your map should run just fine

Comment: @ChrisBrownie55 No, if filteredRestaurantList is undefined at the first render, it'll throw an error because map is not a property on the undefined type. I'll answer this

Comment: At first render, `filteredRestaurantList` is `[]` as defined in the constructor, it can only become undefined if some other function (or reducer) is modifying it

Comment: @SterlingArcher Oh yes, I failed to see the constructor in the provided code. It's exactly what you said, maybe its happening at the `filtering stage` (as the state variable's name suggests) or in the worst case when the response from the API is being assigned to the state property. (in which case things should break way before render()) ;)

Comment: @Ajay Gupta I don't see how it could be undefined it's defined as an empty array. In the code, there is no example that could make it undefined.

Comment: Look at my previous comment while replying to @SterlingArcher, "I failed to see the constructor in the provided code". And I am not saying that this is happening because of `filteredRestaurantList` being `undefined`. It could be anything other than an array.

Comment: @SterlingArcher You are correct. I have tried everything but my backend seems to work fine.There should be a error in my Home Class

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the data from a back-end, then you should first check whether `filteredRestaurantList` is an array which can be done like

```
this.state.filteredRestaurantList && this.state.filteredRestaurantList.map(...)
```

Most likely, this is the issue here. The compiler is throwing an error because, `map()` is allowed on values of Array type.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How should i edit the code ,the back end part is working fine!

Comment: You need to change the `this.state.filteredRestaurantList.map` to what I suggested above in the `render` method of `Home` component

Comment: I have tried this the very first  but nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

you can leverage the object destructuring

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            restaurantList: [],
            filteredRestaurantList: [],
        }
    }

    render(){
        const { filteredRestaurantList = [] } = this.state;

        return(
          <div style={{marginTop:100}}>
            <Header screen="Home" searchHandler={this.searchHandler}/>
            <div>
              <GridList cellHeight={'auto'} cols={this.getGridListCols()}>
                {filteredRestaurantList.map(item =>(
                  <GridListTile key={item.id}>
                    <HomeItem onItemClick={this.itemClickHandler} item={item} />
                  </GridListTile>
                ))}
              </GridList>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
```

Comment: 'filteredRestaurantList' is not defined  no-undef